# Getting along with a possibly passive-aggressive coworker because of different political beliefs

Tags: politics

I'm just about to celebrate my first month in a new job in an IT startup. I love my new office, and I love my new job. And lately I think I'm getting along with my new office mates. There's this sweet girl about my age who added me on Facebook and in the Messenger group chat of all of us ten-some members, where we exchange jokes, banter, and ask around when we would sit down together for lunch.

There's only one hitch: our political views are completely different.

Now I steer clear of political discussions especially at the office. I have tweaked my privacy settings to show nothing of my political persuasions, and I lurk on the political Facebook threads instead of commenting on them. But I am under no illusion that nobody at work will find out in the long run. She tends to be passionate in her views, launching into a brief rant why she thinks some policy or some political candidate sucks or is good. I can't say our coworkers think the same as she does, but I have a feeling she is keen on gathering her inner circle based on how similar the political stands we believe in, and she would probably exclude and bully those who doesn't think the same way as she does.

The Facebook chat she included me in is eerily silent for one day now. But I don't know for sure if what I think is what is happening--that they formed another chat group without me. After all, its the holidays, and we're chilling with our families, and most don't bother their office mates until we meet again in the office. Also, I can't see her on Facebook. No way of telling if she blocked me or just deactivated her profile since I can't view her profile as public (Facebook told me to login first) I can't dare ask my other office mates about it. If they are truly excluding me, I can't give the impression that I know while I don't know what to do about it. That's a position of weakness.

If it were any other person, I wouldn't care. But she is a few months older than I in the office. I don't like tripping over her ego because of the obvious traps in the workplace.

Now I am quite timid, I occasionally banter and buy food when I feel up to it while she brings her baked goods. I truly want to give her the benefit of the doubt that she would be great to get along with. I don't want to set myself up to be bullied, attacked, back-stabbed, or whatever. I mean, I have tons of friends outside work and from my last jobs who has the same political views as she does, and we tend to argue over them. But we have great friendships and great team chemistry up to today.

So how do I get her to:

1. Make her think I agree with her political views;
2. Make her not care about my political views if she knows, instead focusing on her own, or;
3. Prevent her from doing any bullying, passive-aggressive treatement, or etc. simply because we think differently?

Also, for more insight into my situation, I would like to tell several more things:

- We're both in IT, she manages our API, while I do front-end;
- She is in a secret relationship with one of our software QA guys, or so my fellow front-end developer told me;
- That fellow developer probably thinks I suck at my job, but he likes it when I ask questions about the frameworks we use and why he lays down certain coding conventions;
- That same guy and I have been hanging out recently, on account that there was this rush project that another developer left on the eve of the deadline;
- That guy and the girl almost got into an argument about a controversial politician, and I sided with him;
- Everyone in the office, including the girl, was shipping me and that guy because we have similar tastes in movies, we code in the same platform, we are both reserved in our dealings with others, and he speaks more often to me than to them;
- She probably hates it when I hammer my keyboard while I'm in 'the zone," dancing and writhing like a pianist while coding (I'll apologize when we meet again);
- Last time she and I spoke it was about the cake she brought and some suggestions about bedspacing, since we both live far away from work. It was also right before the holiday break.

Thank you, thank you.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I don't see how this doesn't qualify in the criteria for asking questions in this Stackexchange.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about general "getting-along" relationship advice. It's not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic. I think getting-along is an integral part of the workplace, Jim. But I'll keep in mind what you think. I'll make it a point to look for the right Stackexchange for relationship advice. Thank you anyway for telling me what you think this question is. :)

Comment: 90% of this question is irrelevant (eg what relationship rumors exist)  or is projection of your own concerns ("probably hates",  "possibly passive-aggressive"). Just respectfully avoid the topics you know you. disagree on untill you trust each other to disagree respectively. Exactly as you would in any other setting, which is why this isn't a workplace question . The fact that you happen to know her thru the workplace does not make it a workplace question. If you were asking how to reduce office noise because you think she's bothered, that would be a workplace question.

Comment: Why not the obvious?  Logon to Facebook and see if you are still her Friend.

Comment: Frisbee, I only see "Facebook User" where her icon used to be when I'm logged in. Which means two things: either she blocked me or she deactivated her account.

Comment: @Frisbee: That won't work. Witness "frenemies" on Facebook who remain as Facebook "friends".

Comment: @JimG. Frenemies?   Won't work?  Friend with a capital F is just that - are or are you not a Facebook Friend.

Comment: Most of this question seems to be looking for friendship (or dating?) advice rather than Workplace which is why it's getting downvotes. Off topic. And why would you want to be friends with someone who makes such a big thing of politics that are opposite to yours, and who you think might bully you if you told them what you were really like?

Comment: The reason why I asked this question in this Stackexchange is because I believe getting along with colleagues is part of navigating the workplace, (No I am not looking for dates) office friendships and all. Therefore not off-topic at all. Anyway, Rath says I shouldn't think much about getting along as much as I need to do my job anyway. I've resolved to keep that lady at arm's length. After all, it's her fault she discusses politics in the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you wanna get close to her, but you also want to do so from a position of strength. It doesn't look like a true friendship to me. Some of my best friends disagree with me completely on a number of issues, and I respect them for holding and debating their opinion; but of course your colleague (or you) may not see things this way.

I'd advise you to steer well clear of politics and focus on the job. Your mistake wasn't siding with the other guy at that debate they were having, it was expressing an opinion *at all*. Their mistake was debating politics in the office in the first place. If people try to strike up conversation on that topic, say ‘I don't think that's an appropriate subject for the workplace’, and stick to it. Make her respect you as a professional first and as a friend second.

‘Prevent her from doing any bullying, passive-aggressive treatment, or etc. simply because we think differently?’ You have no control over this whatsoever. You can only act once that behavior has been established. You're scared she might be giving you the silent treatment and have you ostracized from the group, but you have no evidence for that either. Just make sure you don't preempt the passive-aggressive treatment (it's easy to get caught up emotionally). Even if the others have moved on to another messaging group, keep using the original for work-related stuff if that's what you were using it for in the first place.  Work is work, friends is friends.

Comment: Please don't correct British English to American English. Behaviour and behavior are both valid depending on your timezone.